# Getting confirmation that user listened to a lesson

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working on an app that provides a set of audio lessons to users. Once user listened to a lesson I want to mark it as completed. The challenge is that I don't get any notifications once the user finished listening to the mp3 file I sent back. The options I see is to explicitly ask the user to say "completed" after the lesson so that I can get a signal that user finished. But it feels awkward.

I'm using Actions SDK. Is there a better way to handle it? Maybe API is going to be expanded to get provide such signals?

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to track this in your media server? Each mp3 file request could be tagged with the user id and then as the assistant server completes the playback you will have a confirmation that at least the mp3 file got played.

Comment: Hi Leon. Sorry, didn't fully understand the proposal. Once my media server returns mp3 I have no way to know if it was played full or half or only the first 10 seconds and then user quit.

Comment: I running into something similar. The issue with tracking the download is that Google does caching of the file before playing. I thought playing a small audio file after the initial audio file would work but it is immediately fetched.